# Adding a div with data()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, append

I am generating a list of flash SWFs, the information comes from an ajax call which returns a json object which i loop through to create the rows of data using my makeAppRow function.

```
makeAppRow = function(myData){
        var myStr = '<div class="fileEntry">'
      myStr = myStr +'<div class="appDate">'+dateFormat(myData.date_swf, "dS mmmm, yyyy, h:MM TT")+'</div>'
      myStr = myStr +'<div class="appName">'+myData.name_swf+'</div>'
      myStr = myStr +'<div class="appOptions" data>'
      myStr = myStr +'<div class="gotoAppBtn" data-options="'+myData+'">Open App</div>'
      myStr = myStr +'</div>'
      myStr = myStr +'</div>'
        $('#appData').append(myStr);
    }
```

I need the json data to be attached to the `gotoAppBtn` so that when its clicked I can read in the data from the attached json object and use it in my click function, as you can see I've been trying to embed the data using the html5 data but I can't get it to work.

```
 <div class="gotoAppBtn" data-options="'+myData+'">Open App</div>
```

I have a function so that when the button is clicked it loads in an swf.

```
$('.gotoAppBtn').live('click', function(){
        //alert('button clicked')
        var myData = $(this).data("options")
        alert('../userfiles/'+myData.id_ugp+'/'+myData.id_swf+'/'+myData.launchfile_swf+'')
        console.log(myData);
        var flashvars = {};     
        var params = {};
        params.menu = "false";
        params.quality = "best";
        params.scale = "noscale";       
        var attributes = {};
        attributes.id = "flashAppDisplay";
        attributes.name = "flashAppDisplay";
        swfobject.embedSWF(
            '../userfiles/'+myData.id_ugp+'/'+myData.id_swf+'/'+myData.launchfile_swf+'', 'flashAppDisplay', myData.width_swf, myData.height_swf,  myData.version_swf ,"../FAVideo/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes)      
    });
```

but the data does not seem to be there, any pointers on where I am going wrong, or a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you post the html that is being output by `makeAppRow`

Comment: `<div class="fileEntry"><div class="appDate">12th February, 2009, 1:00 AM</div><div class="appName">DAT demo Update Feb 09</div><div class="appOptions"><div class="gotoAppBtn">Open App</div></div></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn the `myData` javascript object to string before you put it in the attribute.
Take a look at `JSON.stringify` from [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

You can also use the .data() function

```
$('#appData .gotoAppBtn:last').data("options",myData)
```

Comment: in the end after trying the other suggestions i ened up using this soloution, using this code: $('.gotoAppBtn:last').data("options",myData)` thanks everyone for your help

Answer (score 1):

If you use jquery to create the HTML you will not need to use the `data-` attributes because you can set the data using `$.data`. Here is a strictly jQuery version of your makeAppRow function.

```
$('<div class="fileEntry"></div>')
    .append('<div class="appDate"></div>')
    .find('.appDate')
        .html(dateFormat(myData.date_swf, "dS mmmm, yyyy, h:MM TT"))
        .end()
    .append('<div class="appName"></div>')
    .find('.appName')
        .html(myData.name_swf)
        .end()
    .append('<div class="appOptions"></div>')
    .find('.appOptions')
        .append('<div class="gotoAppBtn">Open App</div>')
        .find('.gotoAppBtn')
            .data(myData)
            .end()
        .end()
    .appendTo('#appData')
```

Comment: ooooh really nice, i had seen this on the jquery docs but really didnt understand it, your example is nice and understandable, whats the `.end()` for never seen that before.

Comment: End returns you to the previous jquery stack. Generally you will use end after you have called `find` or `filter` - modifying the current set of matched elements.

Comment: sorry just another quiky, how do i access the data in my click function? i tried using `var myData = $(this).data()` but it returns undefined in my alert

Comment: The data will be on the element with `class="gotoAppBtn"`. Make sure `$(this)` is that element. Or store the data on which ever element makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can store arbitrary data associated with an html element using [jquery .data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/).  Looking at the documentation, you can attach the data like this inside your `makeAppRow` function -

```
$('#appData').append(myStr);

//After appending
div = $("div.gotoAppBtn")[0];
$.data(div, "data", { options: myData });
```

And then retrieve it like this:-

```
$('.gotoAppBtn').live('click', function(){
   //alert('button clicked')

   div = $("div.gotoAppBtn")[0];
   var myData = $.data(div, "data").options
```

Comment: like this soloution as it works with my existing code, but why use `div = $("div.gotoAppBtn")[0];` surely this would only get the first div with the class of the gotoAppBtn, as there are many divs generated from the json $(this) would be preferable to use, thanks for your time to answer.

Comment: you are welcome. I am not yet sure about why use that. I am a little confused with that too. Do let me know if you find the reason. Thanks